# Vue Question: How would I close the menu when I click a link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

http://rafaelrodrigu.es/

1. Click the hamburger icon
2. Tap a link
3. The page url changes in the background.
4. But the menu does not close. How can I close the menu when I tap a link? The menu is wrapped in a details html element.

How would I remove the details open attribute?

Simple suggetions are welcome, as I'm a designer and I do not know to much about javascript. Thank you!

My code is below for my navigation.

```
    <details>
        <summary class='hamburger'>
          <div class='line line1'></div>
          <div class='line line2'></div>
          <div class='line line3'></div>
        </summary>
        <div class='menuSlide'>
          <div class='column'>
            <label>Pages</label>
            <router-link class='link' to='/'>Home</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/about'>About</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/blog'>Blog</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/connectAndroid'>Connect Android</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/connectIOS'>Connect iOS</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/geCurrent'>GE Current</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/community'>GrabCAD Community</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/print'>GrabCAD Print Mobile App</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/printMobile'>GrabCAD Print Desktop App</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/shop'>GrabCAD Shop Web Pages</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/response'>Instant Response</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/lightforce'>LightForce Orthodontics</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/marketing'>Marketing Graphics</router-link>
            <router-link class='link' to='/services'>Services</router-link>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <label>For Design Assistance Contact Rafael</label>
            <a class='link lowercase' href='mailto:rafael.product.design@gmail.com'>rafael.product.design@gmail.com</a>
            <a class='link' href='tel:16172999714'>(617) 299-9714</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </details>
```

Comment: You'll need to share what Javascript, css, or library is controlling `menuSlide`

Comment: It was pure html. No CSS or JS needed to open it with the details html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [Global Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to your Vue Router instance. Since you're relying on native HTML to control the opening of the menu, you need to find and remove [the `open` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#attr-open), which is how the `<details>` tag manages its open/closed state.

```js
const router = new VueRouter()

router.beforeEach(() => {
  document.querySelector('details').removeAttribute('open')
})
```

Comment: router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  document.querySelector('details').removeAttribute('open')
})

export default router


Thanks that worked Mitch!

Answer (score -1):

You could add a class to all of the links, something like class='link closebar-remove' and add in your JS.

The 'show-menu' after the toggle is in reference to your CSS, and is a placeholder. You will have to fill in that value, but you'd be looking for any of the CSS elements regarding the menuSlide appearing.

```
const closeBar = document.querySelector('.closebar-remove');
const dropMenu = document.querySelector('.menuSlide');

closeBar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    dropMenu.classList.toggle('show-menu');
});
```

If dropMenu.classList.toggle doesn't work, then you can try dropMenu.classList.remove('appropriate-css-class')

Comment: The class list in Vue apps is managed by the Vue renderer, and will be restored from vdom on reactivity updates.